# Doctrine, updating layouts and existing data

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Please imagine you have an live-application with used data in your doctrine-controlled database.
Now you find out that it's necessary to rename some cols and add some others. 
What is the best approach to accomplish this without too much struggling with your data?

Please let my know if it's not clear what I mean, maybe I am just unable to read the manual correctly..

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

renaming is pretty easy:

read about [columan aliases](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/yaml-schema-files%3afeatures-&-examples%3acolumn-aliases)

adding and removing cols is much more tricky.
you could do it by changing the model and afterwards changing the fields in the tables by hand, or you use the doctrine migration to "automaticly" do this job for you:

[Doctrine migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/migrations/en)